# Facebook marketing API - creating multiple ad sets

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'd like to create multiple (e.g. 20) ad sets via Facebook marketing API in web app. Of course Facebook has limitations and I can't do this straight. I spent a lot of time in testing. I'm waiting few minutes after I get error and retry request. But if I haven't ad-account error, faster or sooner I get user limit error.

How can I do this?

I can't catch requests containing multiple methods, because my request (creating ad sets, ad creatives) depends on campaign id. Otherwise it had to be a very big request.

I'm thinking about storing requests in session or database, but my requests depends each others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Batch requests:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/batch-requests/v2.8

Example in python:
api_batch = account.get_api_assured().new_batch()

```
    for whatever in whatever_list:
        # Create the adset
        adset = ....
        adset.remote_create(batch=api_batch, failure=callback_failure)

    api_batch.execute()
```

Comment: It's not a correct answer, because every request  in batch is counting as a separatle API request. 

"We currently limit the number of requests which can be in a batch to 50, but each call within the batch is counted separately for the purposes of calculating API call limits and resource limits. For example, a batch of 10 API calls will count as 10 calls and each call within the batch contributes to CPU resource limits in the same manner."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests#limits